# What is the role of "virtually" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> It is virtually impossible to escape this place!

I don't really understand what is *virtually* doing there. First, I can hardly tell what it means to be *virtual*, and second, I still don't see any extra value added to the sentence compared to

> It is impossible to escape this place!

As far as I can tell, *virtually* seems to simply give **emphasis** to the current situation. But I'm lost.

According to http://www.thefreedictionary.com/virtual,

> 1 . Existing or resulting in essence or effect though not in actual fact, form, or name: *the virtual extinction of the buffalo*.

I don't get that meaning, and I certainly don't even understand the difference between *the virtual extinction of the buffalo* and *the extinction of the buffalo*. Now then, I may have grabbed the wrong definition. Here's the other one:

> 2 . Existing in the mind, especially as a product of the imagination. Used in literary criticism of a text.

This definition seems to suggest me that *virtually* is used to create some kind of **psychological** (of the mind) context. So when they say

> It is virtually impossible to escape this place!

It is meant to say something like "even though it is physically possible to escape, people are too scared to even try to do it - therefore, it is rather impossible to escape".

Not sure. Any ideas about the usage of *virtually*?

**Note**: The context in the sentence I provided is basically this: It is from an article about a community where people are so poor that

> It is virtually impossible to escape this place!

Comment: Note: *Virtual* and *Virtually* are virtually antonymous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're over-thinking it.  `Virtual` here means "in essence, but not in fact".

**to clarify:**

> I certainly don't even understand the difference between *the virtual extinction of the buffalo* and *the extinction of the buffalo*.

Extinct means "no longer in existence; having died out."  For the buffalo to be extinct, every last buffalo must have perished from the Earth.

The North American buffalo is *not* extinct.  There are a few thousand of them left.  They are *virtually* extinct.

> It is virtually impossible to escape this place!

It's very, very difficult to escape, nigh on impossible, but nothing is completely impossible.  Virtually nothing...

**to clarify some more:**  I think *virtually* can be distinguished from *almost*, in that *almost* merely denotes quantitative proximity.  If a bullet whizzed by your head, it *almost* killed you -- but there's a tremendous difference between being almost killed and actually being killed.

*Virtually* means the difference between the current state and the named state is detectable, but not significant.  The buffalo is virtually extinct in the sense that it exists only in a few scattered domesticated herds.  The continental masses of bison that once ruled the Great Plains, their essential buffalo-ness, are gone forever.

Comment: Well, that's good to know. But I still don't get that *in essence, but not in fact* definition well as I mentioned in the question :(

Comment: Your examples establish _virtually_ as a synonym for _almost_. So what's the difference?

Comment: @MrLister -- perhaps it's only a matter of degree.  99 is almost a hundred, but I don't think it's *virtually* one hundred.  *Virtually* is akin to "for all practical purposes".

Comment: +1 @Malvolio "for all practical purposes" (and I just noticed that you are the one who gave this answer. Probably you should include that to your answer?)

Comment: Just because I love being a pedantic hair-splitter, it is not *buffalo* that are virtually extinct, but *bison*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bison

Comment: Please add a reference, at least to show the synonymity of 'virtual' and 'almost'. _I'd almost downvoted until I read your analysis showing that 'virtually' in the sense of 'almost', and 'almost', are by no means totally interchangeable. An interesting area of study. I expect it would be difficult to find analysis here: novel work?_

Answer (score 2):

In these contexts, *virtually* means "almost".

> It is virtually [almost] impossible to escape this place!

and

> It is impossible to escape this place!

are different. The first implies that it is possible, although very difficult. It is the same with your extinct sentence. If an animal is extinct, there are none left. If it is virtually, or almost, extinct, there are very few left and it will be extinct soon, unless something is done to prevent its decline.

Comment: Please add a substantiating reference, linked & attributed.

Answer (score 0):

By "in essence, but not in fact", you should understand that you can escape that place but it draws so much attention that you'd never escape(say without visiting it).

Answer (score 0):

Definition:
virtual = almost or nearly as described, but not completely or according to strict definition.

"Virtually" is used here in context for "Nearly", "Almost" or "Close to".

Examples:

It is 'virtually' impossible to escape this place!
-or-
It is 'nearly' impossible to escape this place!
-or-
It is 'almost' impossible to escape this place!
-or-
It is 'close to' impossible to escape this place!

I hope this makes sense :-D

Answer (score 0):

It is OED sense 1b of the adverb - ***virtually***.

> 1b. In effect, although not according to strict definition; **to all
>   intents and purposes; as good as; practically. Later frequently in
>   weakened use: nearly, almost.**
>
> a1600   R. Hooker Disc. Justif. (1612) 32   No man is ignorant of
>   their first principles, which doe vertually containe whatsoever by
>   naturall meanes, is, or can be knowne.
>
> a1626   L. Andrewes XCVI Serm. (1629) xiv. 131   That was but
>   virtually; as good as borne: This, actually; borne indeed.
>
> 1642   T. Fuller Holy State iii. iv. 160   Continue correspondency
>   with..some Professour or Secretary, who virtually is the whole
>   University, or State.
>
> 1718   M. Prior Alma ii, in Poems Several Occasions (new ed.) 345   By
>   the Peep-holes in his Crest, Is it not virtually confest, That there
>   his Eye took distant Aim.
>
> 1791   E. Burke Appeal New to Old Whigs 16   It is virtually a begging
>   of the question.
>
> 1846   G. H. Haydon Five Years Austral. Felix iii. 26   The several
>   divisions of the country are so vaguely defined as to render accuracy
>   in detail virtually impossible.
>
> 1878   W. E. H. Lecky Hist. Eng. 18th Cent. I. ii. 301   Before the
>   middle of the 18th century the laws against Catholic worship were
>   virtually obsolete.
>
> 1888   Lancet 18 Aug. 335/2   The railway companies commonly submit
>   the eyesight of their servants, virtually their whole staff, to a
>   series of careful tests.
>
> 1940   Amer. Jrnl. Sociol. 45 554   She is still a virtually
>   unsocialized creature.
>
> 1989   C. S. Murray Crosstown Traffic vii. 161   Sunday morning was
>   virtually the high spot of his week.
>
> 2011   Vanity Fair Nov. 188/1   Banks could sell virtually any product
>   they wanted, on any terms.